# TypeError: formatting

Tags: python

I have a problem with:

```
if isinstance(float(a), float) == True and ((a % 2) != 0) or ((a % 2) != 1):
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Factorial.py", line 32, in <module>
    if isinstance(float(a), float) == True and format((a % 2) != 0) or format((a % 2) != 1):
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: looks like `a` is a `str`? then `a % 2` is not a remainder operation, but a string formatting.

Comment: You need to convert `a` first to a float not within the comparison because then in the second condition `a` is still a float.

Comment: Using mod on a float and comparing against 0 and 1 :this  `((a % 2) != 0) or ((a % 2) != 1):` IS TRUE - always. what purpose does it serve?

Answer (score 1):

Better use a `try/except` block:

```
a = "100.0"
try:
    number = float(a)
    if ((number % 2) != 0) or ((number % 2) != 1):
        print("Yes")
except ValueError:
    # do something different here
    pass
```

Your original issue was that you converted `a` to a float but only stored the result within the scope of `isinstance()`. `a` was never changed and later compared as if it already was. Additionally the comparison is pretty useless as it will always print `"Yes"`.

Comment: What float number does not print "Yes" ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner: You're absolutely right, I just copied the original comparison.